# Okular is not listed in the open with option

Tags: permissions, pdf

recently I installed Ocular .I opened file using Ocular through command window.But it is not listing in the normal user.But if I go for sudo nautilus , I am getting Ocular option.
I know it is related to the permission problem for Ocular folder.Please give the exact location of Ocular for giving the permissions needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal(<kbd>Crrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. type `sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file`
3. Then press *Enter*
4. You will be asked for *root* password
5. enter the password.
6. press *Enter*

Now you can access it as a normal file.